# Incorrect $this object inside a module's phtml file

Tags: blocks, layout

I'm using two modules: Webtex_CustomerPrices and FireGento_MageSetup.

There's a block created inside customtierprices.xml(Webtex_CustomerPrices module):

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="content">
       <block type="customerprices/catalog_product_price" name="customtierprices">
           <action method="setTemplate">
               <template>customerprices/customertierprices.phtml</template>
           </action>
       </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

When I write this code in customtierprices.phtml, before any other code:

```
echo get_class($this);
```

I'm getting this output: `FireGento_MageSetup_Block_Catalog_Product_Price`

How is that possible? In the .xml file it is clearly stated that it should be an instance of `customerprices/catalog_product_price`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The class in FireGento/MageSetup/Block/Catalog/Product/Price/Abstract.php is extended as follows:

```
abstract class FireGento_MageSetup_Block_Catalog_Product_Price_Abstract
    extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price
{  }
```

But what I needed was:

```
abstract class FireGento_MageSetup_Block_Catalog_Product_Price_Abstract
    extends Webtex_Customerprices_Block_Catalog_Product_Price
{  }
```

Now I can use Webtex_Customerprices methods in customertierprices.phtml.

I still don't understand though how this could override the block with defined type that was explicitly created in the xml file.

### EDIT

Above solution caused 'unknown class' problems on other pages(catalog, search etc.).

I've reverted to default parent class in Abstract.php and manually created Webtex_Customerprices object in customertierprices.phtml

```
$wcuObj = new Webtex_Customerprices_Block_Catalog_Product_Price();
$_tierPrices = $wcuObj->getCustomTierPrices();
```

Then `$this->getTierPrices()` works fine as it exists somewhere down the inheritance chain starting from `FireGento_MageSetup_Block_Catalog_Product_Price`

Answer (score 0):

You can check config.xml of the FireGento_MageSetup extension - it might have rewrites of the catalog_product_price block.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Dmitry but I haven't found such override in MageSetup's xml files.